# How do I select insert into select a table which already has values in the primary key column without adding new rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ssms

I'm working on a database for my school project in which I have to produce a functional database by normalizing sample tables given to us.
One table I'm having trouble with is itineraries. I produce 3 tables from the normalization which are "Destinations", "Itineraries" and "Itinerary_Destinations".

The code for Destinations is:

```
create table Destinations
(
 DestinationID varchar(5) primary key,
 Name varchar(45)
 );
```

The code for Itineraries is:

```
create table Itineraries
(
 ItineraryID varchar(5),
 Name varchar(45)
 );
```

The code for the last table is:

```
create table Itinerary_Destinations
(
DI varchar(5) primary key,
ItineraryID varchar(5) foreign key references Itineraries(ItineraryID),
Itinerary_Name varchar(45),
DestinationID varchar(5) foreign key references Destinations(DestinationID),
Destination_Name varchar(45)
);
```

Data has already been inserted into all 3 tables with the exception of 'Destination_Name' and 'Itinerary_Name' columns. The code I'm attempting to use is returning as error. The code is shown below.

```
insert into Itinerary_Destinations (Itinerary_name)
select Name from Itineraries where 
Itineraries.ItineraryID = ItineraryID;
```

The error it returns is

> Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 1 Cannot insert the value NULL into
>   column 'DI', table 'DDDAssignment.dbo.Itinerary_Destinations'; column
>   does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. The statement has been terminated.

Is there a method to accomplish the task of inserting the Destination_Name and Itinerary_Name without creating new records that require primary keys?

Or should I do it manually?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to modify records which already exist, then you should be using an `UPDATE` rather than an `INSERT`:

```
UPDATE a
SET Itinerary_name = b.Name
FROM Itinerary_Destinations a
INNER JOIN Itinerary_name b
    ON a.ItineraryID = b.ItineraryID;
```

But, if you do have some data which is not already logically associated with the `Itinerary_Destinations` table, then using an insert is appropriate.

Comment: Thank you very much, I hadn't thought about that. I feel so silly.

Answer (score 0):

use `coalesce` funtion in case null it will insert blank string, as your column does not allow null value thats why you got that error in your query

```
insert into Itinerary_Destinations (Itinerary_name)
select  coalesce(Name,' ') from Itineraries where 
Itineraries.ItineraryID = ItineraryID;
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that